# Credential spec not respected by Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, windows-server-2022

I've got a Docker swarm hosted on Windows Server 2022. I've created a `credentialspec` file since I need the service to use a [gMSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts). I've also defined a compose file to launch my service:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  agent:
    image: privaterepo.local/devops-agent-win-generic:latest
    hostname: '${AZPOOL}_Generic-{{.Task.Slot}}'
    user: "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE"
    security_opt: 
      - "credentialspec=file://domain_devopsagent.json"
    environment:
      AZP_URL: ${AZURL}
      AZP_POOL: ${AZPOOL}
      AZP_TOKEN: ${AZTOKEN}
      AZP_ONCE: ${AZONCE:-false}
      AZP_REMOVE: ${AZREMOVE:-true}
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == windows]
```

This starts the containers fine (no errors), and the containers seem to operate as `NETWORK SERVICE`, as expected, however they do not have access to the network shares as expected.

If I run the container manually then the container DOES have access to the network shares.

```
docker run --rm -it --user "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" --security-opt "credentialspec=file://domain_devopsagent.json" privaterepo/devops-agent-win-generic:latest
```

This leads me to believe there's an issue in either the compose definition or in how the Docker Swarm handles the compose definition.

I've also tried using the `credentialspec=raw://<json>` version - the container launched fine but as before it couldn't access the network shares.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've clearly missed a critical part of the documentation on the compose file structures (specifically [this part](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#example-gmsa-configuration)).

The final definition should look like:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  agent:
    image: privaterepo.local/devops-agent-win-generic:latest
    hostname: '${AZPOOL}_Generic-{{.Task.Slot}}'
    user: "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE"
    credential_spec:
      config: credspec
    environment:
      AZP_URL: ${AZURL}
      AZP_POOL: ${AZPOOL}
      AZP_TOKEN: ${AZTOKEN}
      AZP_ONCE: ${AZONCE:-false}
      AZP_REMOVE: ${AZREMOVE:-true}
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == windows]
configs:
  credspec:
    external: true
```

Prior to launching the above the `credspec` config needs to be created in the swarm via `docker config create` (should contain the original credspec file JSON).